# error Google analytics con power bi

Tags: powerbi

Hola estoy trayendo la información de google analytics, de la vista todos los datos del sitio web. Cuando levanto la información en power bi me muestra datos diferentes a los que veo en google analytics, normalmente en anaylitics tengo mas registros que en la original.

Comment: Hola Kevin, ¿Cómo envías la información de Google analytics a power bi? (Sí tenemos más conocimiento de esta función, te podemos ayudar más, saludos.

Comment: Estoy usando el conector nativo de power bi que habilita conexion directa con la API de google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

1.Has comprobado que esos datos del analystics no sean datos a tiempo real o de rápida actualización? 
La carga de datos de Bi no es automática sino manual comprueba que esto no esté pasando.

2.En caso de que lo anterior esté bien, comprueba que los campos que insertas no estén resumidos en suma que es lo normal, la forma de comprobar esto es en la zona de campos ver si contienen un icono a su izquierda de sumatorio, en dicho caso en la parte de modelado:propiedades:resume predeterminado; ahí comprueba que ponga no resumido sino es así cámbialo.

Estas son mis dos soluciones ya que yo mismo probé dicha implementación y funcionaba correctamente, espero que esto sea una respuesta a tu problema sino espero que también lo comuniques y que quizás especifiques más el problema. Saludos.

---